# I want to be able to catch an error if there is one in a form with Validation

Tags: php, validation, try-catch, kohana-3

Here is the code:

```
try {

        $result = Model_User::update_user($_POST);

            // message: save success
        Message::add('success', __('Values saved.'));
        // redirect and exit
        $this->request->redirect('user/profile');
        return;
     } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Get errors for display in view
        // Note how the first param is the path to the message file (e.g. /messages/register.php)
        Message::add('error', __('Error: Values could not be saved.'));
        $errors = $e->errors('register');
        $errors = array_merge($errors, (isset($errors['_external']) ? $errors['_external'] : array()));
        $view->set('errors', $errors);
        // Pass on the old form values
        $user->password = '';
        $view->set('data', $user);
     }
```

Here is the code of update_user method in Model_User:

```
public function update_user($fields)
    {
            $validation = Validation::factory($fields)
                    ->rules('password', $this->_rules['password'])
                    ->rules('password_confirm', $this->_rules['password_confirm'])
                    ->filters('password', $this->_filters['password']);

            $this->validate($fields);
            $users = CASSANDRA::selectColumnFamily('Users');
            if ($users->get_cout($username))
            {
                    return $users->insert($uuid, array(
                                            'username'      => $fields['username'],
                                            'password'      => $fields['password'],
                                            'email'         => $fields['email'],
                                            'modify'        => date('YmdHis', time()),
                                    ));
            }
            else
            {
                    return $validation;
            }
    }
```

I am now getting this error:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method ErrorException::errors()
```

Stuck on this line:

```
117             $errors = $e->errors('register');
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch a [Validation_Exception](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Validation_Exception) for handling validation errors.

Only this kind of exception has an `errors()` method. Your code is throwing some other kind of exception, for which you need to do the error handling yourself.

So, change

`} catch (Exception $e) {`

to

```
} catch (Validation_Exception $e) {
    $errors = $e->errors('register');
    ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Do your error handling by hand
}
```